# Свойства RichTextBox, миграция с WindowsForms на WPF

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Добрый день всем. Я переписываю академическое приложение, написанное на Windows Forms. Хочу перенести в WPF. Пока не удалось разобраться с RichTextBox и его свойствами.

//chatBox - это имя RichTextBox;

У меня есть метод, который выводит сообщения в RichTextBox
Код используемый в Windows Forms

```
private void AddMessage(string Content,string Color = "Black")
    {
        if(InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(_addMessage,Content,Color);
            return;
        }
        chatBox.SelectionStart = chatBox.TextLength;
        chatBox.SelectionLength = Content.Length;
        chatBox.SelectionColor = getColor(Color);
        chatBox.AppendText(Content + Environment.NewLine);
    }   

private Color getColor(string text)
    {

        if (Color.Red.Name.Contains(text))
            return Color.Red;
        return Color.Black;

    }
```

Я попытался взять эти же свойства в WPF, но не вышло. Как можно переделать код?

Код WPF

```
 `private void AddMe`ssage(string Content, string Color = "Black")
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) // InvokeRequired
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(_addMessage, Content, Color);
            //Dispatcher.Invoke(_addMessage, Content);
            return;
        }
        //chatBox.SelectionStart = chatBox.TextLength;
        //chatBox.SelectionLength = Content.Length;
        //chatBox.SelectionColor = getColor(Color);

        chatBox.AppendText(Content + Environment.NewLine);
    }


private Color getColor(string text)
    {

        if (Color.Red.Name.Contains(text))
            return Color.Red;
        return Color.Black;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё очень просто. Вам не нужно возиться с курсором, вы должны дополнять объектную модель.

У `RichTextBox` есть `Document` (он создаётся по умолчанию, если вы не создали свой явно). У документа есть коллекция абзацев `Paragraphs`, в ней один абзац, если вы не создали свой. В него нужно добавлять элементы в коллекцию `Inlines`.

Получаем такой метод:

```
void AddLine(Paragraph para, string text, Brush color)
{
    para.Inlines.Add(new Run(text) { Foreground = color });
    para.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
}
```

---

Пример использования. Заводим окно:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        Title="Тест" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox Name="RTB"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

и code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Run();
    }

    async void Run()
    {
        var para = (Paragraph)RTB.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock;
        for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            AddLine(para, $"Line #{i + 1}", (i % 2 == 0) ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Green);
        }
    }

    void AddLine(Paragraph para, string text, Brush color)
    {
        para.Inlines.Add(new Run(text) { Foreground = color });
        para.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
    }
}
```

Получаем:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: Спасибо огромное за разъяснение! Но я вот только не пойму, как этот пример применить в моем методе. Не могли бы вы подсказать, как это реализовать?

Comment: @JDo: А что именно непонятно? Вам нужен аналог метода `AddLine`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Это я не верно делал. Все работает!!

Comment: @JDo: Вот и отлично, рад, что помогло!