# Аналог RichTextBox в качестве логгера для WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, richtextbox

Был проект на `WinForms` и в окне для вывода лога выполнения программы использовался `RichTextBox` со следующим кодом:

```
private void writeLog(string line, MessageType type)
{
    this.richTextBox.SelectionStart = this.richTextBox.TextLength;
    this.richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    this.richTextBox.SelectionColor = getDrawColor(type);
    this.richTextBox.AppendText((this.richTextBox.TextLength > 0 ? "\r\n" : "") + line);
    this.richTextBox.SelectionColor = this.richTextBox.ForeColor;
    this.richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
}

private Color getDrawColor(MessageType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case MessageType.SUCCESS:
            return Color.Green;

        case MessageType.WARNING:
            return Color.Red;

        case MessageType.SYSTEM:
            return Color.Blue;

        default:
            return Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Подскажите что лучше использовать для WPF окна или как переделать имеющийся элемент. Как я уже успел заметить свойства некоторых контролов в WPF очень сильно изменены.

Пробовал использовать `TextBox`, но после 200-300 строк начинаются лаги в элементе при добавлении новой строки. Пока использую костыль - периодическую очистку контрола. Но это не комильфо.

Comment: Как по мне логи самое то выводить коллекцией, в некий ListBox. Меняете ему вид (скажем текст что бы выделять засовываете в TextBox, рядом некую пометку типа с привязанным цветом) и получаете отличный как по мне вывод логов, где каждая строка = одному событию. А сплошным текстом выводить с новой строки - это если только в файл, в интерфейсе такое скучно, нудно...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну там не сплошной текст. Каждая строка отдельное событие со своим цветом текста. Просто я ума не приложу как теперь всё это выглядеть должно. Понятно, что функционал стал более гибким за счёт увеличения писанины. Но подробных примеров, учитывающих мои особенности нет. По крайней мере я не нашёл. [Вот](https://i0.wp.com/rootware.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Infrared_Station_Review.jpg) пример.

Comment: Мне кажется, такой вопрос уже был на ruSO

Comment: @АндрейNOP да. Вы правы. [Нашёл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671282/Свойства-richtextbox-миграция-с-windowsforms-на-wpf?rq=1).

Comment: Не, не этот, был вопрос именно про производительность

Comment: Было бы интересно почитать, чтобы знать на будущее.

Comment: Вот [кстати](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709828/richtextbox-для-wpf-шустрее-чем-родной) человек с той же проблемой, в ответе используется ListView, который прекрасно работает с 500к строк. Основное преимущество такого подхода в виртуализации, да и каждое событие лога записано отдельно в коллекции, что дает возможность в управление ей (поиск, удаление, изменение, вывод определенных и др.)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо. Сохранил в заметках. Но на данный момент это слишком круто для моего приложения.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ага, именно тот топик имел ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ частично содержался в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671282/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-richtextbox-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-windowsforms-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wpf?rq=1) вопросе. Конечный вариант оказался более лаконичен, чем для `WinForms`.

```
private void writeLog(string line, MessageType type)
{
    Paragraph para = (Paragraph) this.richTextBox.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock;

    SolidColorBrush color;
    switch (type)
    {
        case MessageType.SUCCESS:
            color = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
            break;
        case MessageType.WARNING:
            color = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
            break;
        case MessageType.SYSTEM:
            color = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue;
            break;
        default:
            color = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
            break;
    }

    if (para.Inlines.Count > 0)
        para.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

    para.Inlines.Add(new Run(line) { Foreground = color });
}
```

Comment: Лучше было бы перенести задачу выбора цвета в конвертер или шаблон элемента, код не должен заниматься вопросами отображения

Comment: Ну чисто логически количество шагов будет идентичным при каждом добавлении строки. Просто код окна будет содержать больше "мусора". А так, оптимизация чисто эстетического характера. Или я не прав?

Comment: Код будет больше, но каждый его кусок будет заниматься чем-нибудь одним: View показывать, ViewModel предоставлять данные и т.д. Так на уровне генерации логов вы сможете оставить только уровень события, а задачу отображения полностью отделить и в будущем заменить на любое другое отображение не меняя кода